# custom UICollectionViewCell class recognize but not working

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift2, uicollectionviewcell, xcode7

I implemented a custom class for my collectionview cells.
The class recognize the attributes like labels but when i run my app the label text doesn't display.
Class is register like this :

```
  self.collectionView!.registerClass(StatsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

here is the init method of the custom cell class:

```
var textlabel = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let width = frame.size.width
    let height = frame.size.height
    textlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width,height))
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

and the implementation :

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StatsCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textlabel.text = "test"

    return cell
}
```

Could someone point me to my mistake please, i'm a bit lost here, cannot see what's wrong.

Note that i can use the cell properties (meaning the cell is in fact here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put `textlabel` in a `view`.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let width = frame.size.width
    let height = frame.size.height
    textlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width,height))
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(textlabel) // add text label to view
}
```